# How to run a bash script via absolute path?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, bash, shell

I have a file:

```
/Users/danylo.volokh/test/test_bash_script.sh
```

Content is very simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "-- print from script"
```

I'm in folder "danylo.volokh"

**This command runs fine:**

```
Danilos-MacBook-Pro:~ danylo.volokh$ test/test_bash_script.sh 
-- print from script
```

**But if I try to run in with absolute path I get an error:**

```
Danilos-MacBook-Pro:~ danylo.volokh$ /test/test_bash_script.sh 
-bash: /test/test_bash_script.sh: No such file or directory
```

I want to run a command with absolute path from any folder and get the script to be executed.

Comment: The absolute path is `/Users/danylo.volokh/test/test_bash_script.sh` not `/test/test_bash_script.sh`

Comment: This question has a basic understanding problem. VTC?

Comment: I don't get it. you apparently know the full path of your script, yet you won't use it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### I want to run a command with absolute path from any folder and get the script to be executed.

> If I try to run in with absolute path I get an error:

```
/test/test_bash_script.sh 
-bash: /test/test_bash_script.sh: No such file or directory
```

File `/test/test_bash_script.sh` does not exist, and so cannot be executed.

- An absolute path is defined as the specifying the location of a file or directory from the root directory (`/`).
- `/test` cannot be an absolute path as the directory `/test` **does not exist** (it is a subdirectory of your home directory).

You have two choices:

1. Use the correct absolute path to the script:

   ```
   /Users/danylo.volokh/test/test_bash_script.sh
   ```
2. Use the path based on your home directory:

   ```
   ~/test/test_bash_script.sh
   ```

---

#### What is an absolute path?

> An absolute path is defined as the specifying the location of a file or directory from the root directory (`/`).

Source [Absolute path vs relative path in Linux/Unix](http://www.linuxnix.com/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix/)

> Since slashes always separate name components, if a pathname starts
>   with a slash, the nameless "ROOT" directory is assumed to begin the
>   pathname. The ROOT directory has no name. It is the root of the entire
>   Unix file system tree.
>
> **A pathname starting with a slash is called an absolute pathname, since
>   it always starts at the ROOT.**
>
> Because it is difficult to talk about a directory that has no name, we
>   usually (incorrectly) use the name "/" (slash) for the ROOT directory.
>   This is wrong, because name components of a pathname can’t contain
>   slashes and slashes separate name components. Understand that when we
>   use "/" for ROOT, we really mean "the nameless ROOT directory that is
>   to the left of the slash", not the slash itself.

Source [Unix/Linux Pathnames (absolute, relative, dot, dot dot)](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8207/12f/notes/160_pathnames.html)

Comment: @tatsu "It is absolutely unreal to me that executing sh scripts from absolute path is prevented" it is not prevented. Please read the answer carefully.

Comment: @tatsu Why are you adding `.` to an absolute path? `.` refers to the current directory ... please read the answer carefully and the link in the answer as well.

Comment: ok I read. from what I understand whithout the dot it should work. EDIT : yep it does work. this is just confusing. how can they expect us to guess this stuff?

Answer (score 2):

The absolute path is `/Users/danylo.volokh/test/test_bash_script.sh`, not `/test/test_bash_script.sh`. Bash is right then.

Answer (score 0):

if "this is your full absolute path /Users/danylo.volokh/test/test_bash_script.sh"
then
if you are in Users
then
the exec path will be "danylo.volokh/test/test_bash_script.sh"
else if you are in danylo.volokh
then
the exec path will be "test/test_bash_script.sh"
else if you are in test
then
the exec path will be "./test_bash_script.sh"
else if you do not know where in this world you are
then
the exec path will be "/Users/danylo.volokh/test/test_bash_script.sh"

this is for future users who need help with basic logic or if the op still doesnt have the answer (that would be embarrassing)

p.s this should work flawlessly in linux you might have to change it a bit for windows